# Branch.io Smart Banner Journey Unable to Detect If App Downloaded

Tags: branch.io

I have implemented a branch.io journey smart banner, and I want to use its detection feature to tell if my app has been downloaded or not.

However, that data is coming back null.

Here is my code:

```
import { BRANCH_KEY } from 'constants';

import branch from 'branch-sdk';

import './styles.scss';

branch.init(BRANCH_KEY, {}, (err, data) => {
  console.log('data', data);
});
```

output from console.log is this:

```
{data: "{"+clicked_branch_link":false,"+is_first_session":true}",
data_parsed: {…},
has_app: null,
identity: null,
referring_identity: null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branch uses a probabilistic method of detecting if a user has an app installed on the device using URI schemes and persona data. Please note that you should not rely on the *has_app* parameter as it is computed probabilistically on the Branch servers and the accuracy automatically increases with the number of times Branch sees the particular device on the Branch network.